# Evaluation of $dx$ in trigonometric substitution

Tags: calculus, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

In evaluating integrals through trig substitution, I often see $dx$ get evaluated to something when substituting $x$ for something in terms of $\theta$. For example, in Sal Khan's explanation of $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dx$$ he evaluates $x=2sin\theta$ using the relationships between sides in a right triangle, which makes perfect sense to me, but then he sets $dx=2cos\theta d\theta$ without any explanation as to why that is mathematically valid or how you can do that. I was always of the understanding that $dx$ simply represented the variable of integration and was relatively immutable. How does this work, and why is it permissible?

Comment: Non-rigorously this is because $x = 2\sin\theta$ implies $dx/d\theta = 2\cos\theta$ so $dx = 2\cos\theta d\theta$.

Comment: Integrating the chain rule $(F(g(x)))'=F'(g(x))g'(x)$, and calling $f=F'$ and $y=g(x)$, gives that $\int f(y)dy = F(y)= F(g(x)) =\int(F(g(x)))'dx = \int F'(g(x))g'(x)dx=\int f(g(x))g'(x)dx$. In other words, changing coordinates from $y$ to $y=g(x)$, changes the integrand from $f(y)$ to $f(g(x))g'(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
x&=2\sin\theta\\
\frac{d}{d\theta}(x)&=\frac{d}{d\theta}(2\sin\theta)\\
\frac{dx}{d\theta}&=2\cos\theta\\
dx&=2\cos\theta\ d\theta
\end{align}

Treating the $d\theta$ like a denominator is *almost always* permissible when working with single variable calculus.

Comment: When mathematics is done like theology. Amen!